# Want to skip waiting for the JMS timeout in case of the error

Tags: java, rest, timeout, jms, apache-camel

I     am     using   JMS Message message=Connection.receive(timeout-10 secs) method.

In case there is an error in the Camel route,it goes to the onException and is handled by the errorHandlerProcessor which throws an exception`` explicitly.

The problem is,I do get this exception in the console but not on the browser.Because of the receive(timeout),in case of an exception,the queue waits for 10 secs and then displays the message "Message is not received from queue".I want that in case I am throwing an exception explicitly in the errorhandlerprocessor(that gets called in case of some error in the camel route),then the queue should not wait for the timeout,it should simply display the exception I am printing in the errorhandler processor.

In the Eclipse console,in case of an error,I get this exception "error !!!".

But the replyQ on the browser waits for 10 secs and then displays the message
"Reply is not received from queue" instead of printing ""error !!!"

Is there a way through which I can skip waiting for the timeout in case of an error?

Keeping in mind,I do need the timeout and hence,need to use the receive(timeout) method only.

Suggestions any?

```css
   eg.I have the following classes.
    

CamelRoute class

onException(Exception.class)
.handled(true)
.process(errorProcessor)
.end();


 


Resource class

       Message message = consumer
.receive(10000)));

if (message == null) {
connection.close();
consumer.close();
throw new ResultNotFoundException("Message is not received from queue");
}




ErrorProcessor class:-

public class NewProcessor implements Processor {
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
throw new ApplicationException("error !!!");
}
```